# performItemClick on item in Android Navigation Drawer not working

Tags: android, listview, broadcastreceiver, navigation-drawer

I have a sliding drawer, and in the drawer is a ListView with 4 items. I would like to use `performItemClick` to programmatically click one of the items in the drawer, but no matter what I try the code seemingly does nothing. When the item is clicked it's supposed to replace the fragment currently in view with another fragment, and change the action bar title. But none of those things happen with I run `performItemClick`.

Here is the `performItemClick`, in a `BroadcastReceiver` which is receiving a Broadcast

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          mDrawerList.performItemClick(mDrawerList.getAdapter().getView(1, null, null),1,mDrawerList.getAdapter().getItemId(1));
          Log.d("receiver", "Got message + item clicked");
      }
};
```

And here is the code for the actual activity which contains the `performItemClick` and the drawer itself, along with the drawers fragments (the `performItemClick` is near the bottom).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.text.Html;

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private String Data, Band, Number, Class, Teacher, Title, Date, Type, Description, DescriptionAll, DescriptionCheck;
    // Declare Variables
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    LinearLayout mDrawerLinear;
    TextView mWelcomePerson;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
    String actionbar_colors, background_colorsString;
    private String Show_View;
    String[] title;
    String[] count;
    int[] icon;
    private String counterss;
    private int counters;
    Fragment fragment1 = new FragmentsView();
    Fragment fragment2 = new FragmentsHomeworkDue();
    Fragment fragment3 = new FragmentSettings();
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




 SharedPreferences sharedprefers = getSharedPreferences("first_run", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );


       if(sharedprefers.contains("first_run")){


       }else{


           SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor = getSharedPreferences("first_run", Context.MODE_PRIVATE ).edit();



            localEditor.putString("first_run", "ran for the first time");


                localEditor.commit();


           Intent intenter = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);





            finish();




        startActivity(intenter);


       }


        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);


        SharedPreferences sharedpre = getSharedPreferences("show_view", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );


        Show_View = sharedpre.getString("show_view", "");




        SharedPreferences sharedpref = getSharedPreferences("actionbar_color", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );





         if(!sharedpref.contains("actionbar_color")){

             getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#03a9f4")));



         }else{

            actionbar_colors = sharedpref.getString("actionbar_color", null);

            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(actionbar_colors)));

         }


        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();

       bar.setIcon(
               new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent))); 








        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();


SharedPreferences Today_Homework = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("due_today", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



        if(Today_Homework.contains("duetoday_content")){



        parse_due_today_string();





        }else{

            counterss = "";

        }


        if(Show_View.equals("Homework Due")){


        title = new String[] { "Homework Due", "Schedule", "Options", "Logout" };


        icon = new int[] { R.drawable.ic_action_duehomework, R.drawable.ic_action_go_to_today, R.drawable.ic_action_settings, R.drawable.ic_action_logout };


        if(counterss == null && counterss.isEmpty()){

            count = new String[] { "", "", "", "" };

             } 
        else{

                 count = new String[] { counterss, "", "", "" };

             }



        }else{

            if(counterss == null && counterss.isEmpty()){

                count = new String[] { "", "", "", "" };

                 }else{

                     count = new String[] { "", counterss, "", "" };

                 }

            title = new String[] { "Schedule", "Homework Due", "Options", "Logout" };

             icon = new int[] { R.drawable.ic_action_go_to_today, R.drawable.ic_action_duehomework, R.drawable.ic_action_settings, R.drawable.ic_action_logout };




        }



        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mWelcomePerson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Person);

        mWelcomePerson.setText("Lincoln Bernard");

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);


        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(MainActivity.this, title,
                icon, count);


        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);


        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());


        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };




        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }



        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
              new IntentFilter("up_navigation"));

    }






    public void parse_due_today_string() {

         SharedPreferences Today_Homework = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("due_today", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

         String Due_Today = Today_Homework.getString("duetoday_content", "");




        ArrayList<String> description = new ArrayList<String>( );

        StringBuilder DescriptionAll = new StringBuilder();

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Due_Today.getBytes());


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));



        try {

            int i = 0;

            while ((Due_Today = reader.readLine()) != null) {   
        String[] part = Due_Today.split("\",\"", -1);
        int noOfItems = part.length;
        int counter=0;


        DescriptionCheck = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
        counter++;

        Band = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
        counter++;
        Number = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
        counter++;
        Class = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
        counter++;
        Teacher = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
        counter++;
        Title = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
        counter++;
        Date = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
        counter++;
        Type = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
        counter++;
        Data = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
        counter++; 



        if (Type != null && !Type.isEmpty()){        

                counters = ++i;

                counterss = Integer.toString(counters);

        Log.i("Counter","Number of children: "+ counters); 



        }

              }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        finally {


        }


     }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerLinear)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinear);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerLinear);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }


    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


        if(Show_View.equals("Homework Due")){

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment2);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3);
            break;
        }


        }else{


             switch (position) {
             case 0:
                 ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment1);
                 break;
             case 1:
                 ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
                 break;
             case 2:
                 ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3);
                 break;
             }
        }



        ft.commit();


        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        /
        setTitle(title[position]);

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinear);
    }




    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

    }





    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();


      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);

    }


    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {




            Log.d("receiver", "Got");


            mDrawerList.performItemClick(mDrawerList.getAdapter().getView(1, null, null),1,mDrawerList.getAdapter().getItemId(1));


          Log.d("receiver", "Got message");




      }
    };


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {

            manager.popBackStack();

        } else {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

MenuListAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    Context context;
    String[] mTitle;
    String[] mCount;
    int[] mIcon;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MenuListAdapter(Context context, String[] title, 
            int[] icon, String[] count) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mTitle = title;
        this.mIcon = icon;
        this.mCount = count;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTitle.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mTitle[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView txtTitle;

        ImageView imgIcon;

        TextView txtCount;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent,
                false);


        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        txtCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);



        imgIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);


        txtTitle.setText(mTitle[position]);

        txtCount.setText(mCount[position]);



        imgIcon.setImageResource(mIcon[position]);

        return itemView;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? What's supposed to happen when that item is clicked?

Comment: When the item is clicked it's supposed to replace the fragment currently in view with another fragment and change the action bar title

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is something like this inside my Expandable listview adapter for Drawer..

```
View.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    switch (groupPosition) 
                    {
                    case 0:
                        switch (childPosition) 
                        {
                        case 0:

                            if (groupPosition == 0 && childPosition == 0) 
                            { some code }
```

Edit: this switch starts different activity (or change view if fragment) on each respective item click.. in your case their will be fragments..

Comment: so does this switch their position in the listview or does this switch which one is in view?

Comment: it will switch the current actvity in my case on item click, you can change view in the fragment..

Comment: I think I already have something like this, when the user clicks on an item in the drawer. My goal is to programmatically mimic the clicking of an item in the drawer. I am confused about how this will accomplish what I need.

Comment: you are setting mMenuAdapter but i can't see the class definition of it.. can u post it

Comment: added menulistadapter and i almost forgot to thank you for your help so far

Comment: My final thoughts are that u are providing only position in selectItem(position), but not the view as i did bcz the list is generating inside an adapter which has some view so u must provide the item click position in side that view, not just a simple item position, bcz your list is inside adapter..

Comment: yes do something like make your select item inside getview of your list adapter and set View.setOnClickListener their so that you can click on the item of view that you are making..

Comment: I am not a good explainer but i guess i tried my level best here.. Hope U can get something out of this.